# How to use neutral language resources as fallback?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, resx

I have a single solution which contains:

- `LocalizationStringRes.resx` - Holding neutral resources, currently in English.
- `LocalizationStringRes.en.resx` - Holding the English translation values.
- `LocalizationStringRes.de.resx` - Holding German translation values.

I also have a combobox in my application where the language can be selected. Currently it contains "German" and "English". Besides that I am checking the user's system settings for language.

So lets say the user picks "English", then the `LocalizationStringRes.en.resx` will automatically be used when fetching values, because the application will look up files with `en` in them.

I think that holding English translation in both `LocalizationStringRes.resx` and `LocalizationStringRes.en.resx` is double data storage I want to avoid. So I tried simply removing `LocalizationStringRes.en.resx`.

**What I was Expecting:**

- I expected that once the user picks English as his/her language the application will look up a file with `en` in it. If it doesn't find any it will automatically use `LocalizationStringRes.resx` as fallback.

**What actually happened:**

- The `LocalizationStringRes.de.resx` was used as fallback displaying the German translation values.

How can I force my application to always use neutral language values if no `.resx` file is found for the according language string (`en-US`, `fr-FR` etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

You may add

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.MainAssembly)]
```

to the AssemblyInfo.cs